# Some confusion about redis SISMEMBER complexity

Tags: redis

How is the redis command `SISMEMBER set1 member1` complexity O(1) as it should scan the whole set to identify "member1" ?

Comment: A set is not an array. There's no scanning there. It's basically a hashmap without the values. Read up on how hash maps work.

Comment: In short, if you have a value ("member1"), you _know_ where it should be located. So you just go there and check. Hence the O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Because it use hashtable.

Every element in the set will be hashed into a 32-bit string like: `fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0`. the 32-bit string will always be different for different strings. And no matter how long the origin string is, the hashed string will always be 32-bit long.

when redis want to know if a string is in the set, it hashed the origin string first, and then check if the 32-bit string is in the set.

for example, the 32-bit string of "helloworld" is `fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0`, if redis want to check if "helloworld" is in a set, then it will turn out to check if `fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0` is in a set.

Just like you look for a word in a dictionary.

1. redis finds all strings which startswith `f`
2. redis finds all strings whose second char are `c` from the result of step 1.
3. redis finds all strings whose third char are `5` from the result of step 2.
4. repeat and repeat.

So, no matter how long the origin string is, redis will at most query for 32 times, can it know if an origin string is in a set.

So, the complexity is O(1)